# Scrape elements by name and their properties and then print them - Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm completely new to Puppeteer, node.js and programming and I have this project on my mind. [There is a game website](https://www.pathofexile.com/trade/search/Harvest/KljDh5) where you can post your items for sale. I would like to scrape this page and print out all items with their names and properties, but don't know how to reach them.

[Website code looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEAyS.png).

Red lines are what I would like to print out. I've tried to at least get the names of items, but all I get is an empty array:

```
const itemNames = await page.evaluate(() =>
        Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('itemHeader doubleLine'))
            .map((partner) => partner.innerText.trim())
            )

    console.log(itemNames);
    await browser.close();
```

How can I achieve this task with Puppeteer? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try switching to `document.querySelectorAll(".itemHeader.doubleLine")`

Comment: Hi @Karolis Gaivenis, if you are sharing HTML code as well to illustrate your question please make sure to paste it as a code snippet and not as a screenshot, like this those who are willing to help you are able to reproduce your scenario locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) to get the matching elements:

`page.$$eval(selector, pageFunction[, arg])`

> This method runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the page and passes it as the first argument to `pageFunction`.

Then you can iterate over the array of matching elements with an `Array.map` to retrieve their innerText properties.

For example:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.itemHeader.doubleLine')
const items = await page.$$eval('.itemHeader.doubleLine', itemElements => itemElements.map(i => i.innerText.trim()))
```

Ouput:

```
["Damnation Stride\nHydrascale Boots","Corruption Span\nCarnal Boots","Rift Span\nShagreen Boots","Storm Tread\nGoliath Greaves","Maelström Urge\nStrapped Boots","Maelström Tread\nIronscale Boots","Beast Hoof\nCarnal Boots","Ambush Road\nShackled Boots","Miracle Track\nVelvet Slippers","Brood League\nLeatherscale Boots"]
```

---

### Edit

Actually your solution is correct as well. I am pretty sure the thing that is missing in your case is the [`page.waitForSelector`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options). You define `itemNames` before the content would be rendered in the DOM.

```
await page.waitForSelector('.itemHeader.doubleLine')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answers were really helpful. All 3 solutions works (getElementsByClassName, querySelectorAll, page.$$eval). The issue as @theDavidBarton indicated pointed out, was that I was missing page.waitForSelector